# Decompose time series with yearly interval

Tags: r, time-series

I have data spanning over 17 years, and I would like to make a time series at the year level with `ts()`. It works very fine for 1,3 and 6 month intervals, but when I try per year I get an error.

Here is my example:

```
date <- c("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-01-01", "2003-01-01", "2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01")
var <- c(1:17)
df <- data.frame(as.Date(date), var)
ts_df <- ts(df$var,start=c(2000,1),frequency=1)
stl_df <- stl(ts_df, s.window = "periodic")
```

Is there a way around this problem?

I've read that for months you need a minimum of 24 months to model it. Should I have the same minimum amount of values for years too? I'm open to using other tools too if they help solve this...

My goal ultimate goal is to use:

```
autoplot(cbind(Data=ts_df,Seasonal=seasonal(stl_df),
               Trend=trendcycle(stl_df)), 
         facets=TRUE)

date <- c("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-01-01", "2003-01-01", "2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01")
var <- c(1:17)
df <- data.frame(as.Date(date), var)
ts_df <- ts(df$var,start=c(2000,1),frequency=1)
stl_df <- stl(ts_df, s.window = "periodic")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have more varied example:

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="1 year")
var <- cumsum(rnorm(17))

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(date), var)
ts_df <- ts(df$var,start=c(2000,1),frequency=1)
```

I'm afraid you can't decompose seasonality from ts with time intervals >= year. It's just against the seasonality definition, and `stl` or `decompose` have not much to do here. What you can do in this case is decompose **trend** and **cyclical** pattern instead of **seasonality**. There are several smoothing/filtering methods in `mFilter` which is easy to implement. For example Hodrick Prescott filtering:

```
library(mFilter)
filtered <- mFilter(ts_df,filter="HP")
print(filtered)
summary(filtered)
residuals(filtered)
fitted(filtered)
plot(filtered)
```

[image]

And more 'fancy' method which uses **Multiresolution Analysis Of Time Series** in package `wavelets`. This method can provide you decomposed series of **smoothed** values (S), **residuals** and **cyclical patterns** (D1,D2,..., DJ). This package does not have default charting method so there is more to do - just a little:

```
library(waveslim)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
filtered <- mra(ts_df,J=2)

results <- as.data.frame(filtered)
results <- cbind(df,results)

melt(results, id.var="date") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=value,group=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a nice approach of the problem.